# Stylesheets not working on Heroku

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've been trying to get my CSS to work correctly in my Rails app.  I just added 
`config.serve_static_assets = true` to my `config/application.rb` to try to get the assets to precompile.  Before some of the CSS was working but not enough, and now all of the styling has been removed and its just displaying the HTML.

I ran `rake assets:precompile` but that didn't work either.  What can I do to get my styling to work in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your assets pre-compiled files and try to push to heroku again. Heroku will compile it. Hope it helps.

Comment: You mean delete my photos and stylesheets from my local environment and push to heroku, then re-add and push to heroku? Not quite sure.

Comment: Delete only the precompiled files not the original ones under public/assets folder of your local environment

Comment: Hey I am having the same problem again.  But there are no images in my public/assets folder to delete and recompile.  any idea on why this isn't the same fix?

Comment: make sure your css files have extension filename.css.scss if you are not using less.

Comment: I had to precompile again, then delete, then push to heroku.